# How to reverse match multiple Django admin sites (Custom admin site namespaces)

Tags: django

When you extend `AdminSite` to create another admin site how do you go about being able to reverse match each site? It seems the `admin` namespace is hardcoded `reverse('admin:index')`, is there a way to supply a custom namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be confused with the namespace in django. If you are interested to clarify that confusion, you may read up the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/pc5A3qrvITQ).

If you want to try solve your problem, there is a [specific documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf) for multiple admin sites.

> Below are example solutions mostly copied from official documentation

### Example Solution:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from .sites import basic_site, advanced_site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^basic-admin/', basic_site.urls),
    url(r'^advanced-admin/', advanced_site.urls),
]
```

And

```
# sites.py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Monty Python administration'

basic_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadminbasic')
advanced_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadminadvanced')
```

Reversing

```
reverse('myadminbasic:index')    # /basic-admin/
reverse('myadminadvanced:index') # /advanced-admin/
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'd missed the `basic_site.urls` import, i was just using the generic admin ones :)